# How can I list posts in a feed by the most recently created?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angularjs-orderby

I use Onymos for my backend. When I pull my data from onymos it gives me an "arrange by" property where I can specify "createdTime" as the value, however, this doesn't carry over to my template for some reason. I don't think there is an order by directive in angular anymore from my googling. So I'm not sure how else I can order this in my template. 
My service passes an array to a callback function which fires in the contstructor of the main TS page. 
I put a bounty on this because the first solution someone provided didn't work for me.. kept causing errors.

**HOME.HTML**

```
<ion-card id="card" *ngFor="let event of listOfEvents" >      

    <ion-row id="row1">
        <ion-col>
           <span class="showDetails">Date:</span>
           {{getFormattedTime(event.eventTime, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <span class="showDetails">Time:</span>
            {{getFormattedTime(event.eventTime, 'HH:MM')}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <span class="showDetails">Venue:</span>
            {{event.venue}}
        </ion-col>                                                   
    </ion-row>

</ion-card>
```

**MyService.TS**

```
getPosts (selectedCity, successCallback, failureCallback) {

        OnymosUtil.getData(

            '/events/' + selectedCity,      
            function getPostsSuccess (listOfEventsObject){
                successCallback(listOfEventsObject);
            },//close function getPostSuccess
            function getPostsFailure (error) {              
                failureCallback(error);
            },
            {
                orderByField: 'createdTime', //OrderByField not working 
                limitToFirst: 100
        });

    }//end getPosts
```

**HOME.TS**

```
export class Home {

    listOfEvents: Array<any> = []; 
    postEvent: any; 

    constructor (public navCtrl: NavController,
                 public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
                 public getPostSrvc: getPostsService) {

        this.listOfEvents = [];
        let that = this; 

        this.getPostSrvc.getPosts(
           this.selectedCity,
           function getPostsSuccess (listOfEventsObject) {
                for (var i in listOfEventsObject) {
                    that.listOfEvents.push(listOfEventsObject[i]);
                }
           },
           function getPostsFailure (error) {
             console.log('ERROR : home.ts : Failed retrieving Posts - ' + error);
            });
    }//close constructor 
}//close class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array reverse method found here worked best for me: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp

```
this.getPostSrvc.getPosts(
           this.selectedCity,
           function getPostsSuccess (listOfEventsObject) {
                for (var i in listOfEventsObject) {
                    that.listOfEvents.push(listOfEventsObject[i]);
                }
                       **that.listOfEvents.reverse();** 
           },
           function getPostsFailure (error) {
             console.log('ERROR : home.ts : Failed retrieving Posts - ' + error);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just sort it client side:

```
function successCallback (listOfEventsObject) {

    for (var x in listOfEventsObject) {
        that.listOfEvents.push(listOfEventsObject[x]);
    }
    // sort
    that.listOfEvents = that.listOfEvents.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.createdTime - b.createdTime;
        // or vice versa
        // or any other way you wish to sort
    });

}
```

Comment: so inside the sort function would I re-push each item into an array? I need an array to pass to the template. I'm not sure how the a, b, arguments help..

Comment: Look at the JavaScript sort documentation.

Comment: @Spilot Did you try to implement this comment?

Comment: @Duannx... yes and it didn't work. Nothing happens at all, no errors per se, but my list is in the same order as always and not the order I want.

Comment: You need to provide some output, console logs, something.

Comment: @Spilot Do you understand how the `sort` function work?

Answer (score -1):

- You really need to find out why you cannot sort on the server. For a production version of the app, sorting on the client can become very expensive and slow down your app specially if your list of events get updated by just one or two events. 
  Perhaps you can use a better coding for `createdTime`. Have you tried converting this field to a timestamp value? You can do this for example by using [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

  `event.createdTime = moment().valueOf()`
- The client side sorting suggested by other users is the way to go in the absence of the server sort. However, you can make it a bit more optimal, by inserting and keeping the array sorted at the same time.

You can use the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#sortedIndex) library (or write it yourself) to find the index of where to push, and use the following function instead of normal `push`:

```
  sortedPush( array, value ) {
      array.splice( _.sortedIndex( array, value ), 0, value );
  }
```